# Should a ! function return anything?

Tags: arguments, julia, side-effects

In the style guide it says that functions that modify their arguments should be marked with a `!`. However in the [example](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/style-guide/#Append-!-to-names-of-functions-that-modify-their-arguments-1) given the function `double!` returns  the modified argument `a`. Why return it if it has already been modified? Is it necessary?

Comment: It doesn't cost anything any enables you do something like `b = double!(a)*x` in a single line if you needed to.

Comment: or even `double!(double!(a))`

Comment: As Alexander said, it's convention to have it return the modified container.

Comment: @AlexanderMorley by popular vote, it seems you have been chosen to write the Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't cost anything and enables you do things like:

```
b = double!(a)*x
```

or

```
double!(double!(a))
```

in a single line if you needed to.

For that reason (i.e. convenience), it has become convention.